# Keep getting "Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno" error when uploading code

Tags: arduino

I have just bought an Arduino UNO R3 and I'm trying to get a small LED to blink every other second. But each time I try to verify or upload the code, I get the same error: "Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno". I have selected the correct board and port, and I have connected the LED correctly. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
void setUp()
{
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing like 4/5 of the error message.

> undefined reference to `setup'

is part of it.

Rename `setUp` to `setup` and it will compile.

See [Arduino TUTORIALS > Built-In Examples > 01.Basics > BareMinimum](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BareMinimum)

> This example contains the bare minimum of code you need for a sketch
>   to compile properly on Arduino Software (IDE): the `setup()` method and
>   the `loop()` method.

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. It needs to be:

```
void setup() {
}
```

Check this out: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/sketch/setup/

The IDE cannot find your Setup function, that's the problem.